# Paste into image within image with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

Using JS (or jQuery) and CSS, I am trying to build a web page that enables the positioning of one image inside a very specific rectangular area of another image. Think of how *Paste Into* works in Photoshop; that is conceptually what I'm trying to achieve.

I was looking deeply into the excellent [cropperjs](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/) library, thinking that would provide an efficient way to do this (without reinventing a bunch of wheels) and so I made [this post](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/discussions/1020) within the cropperjs forum. But the developer of cropperjs posted this as a response:

> I think you may need another library, this library may not fit your
> purpose.

Now to describe my need in more detail:

Begin with IMAGE #1. This will be an image on the web page that doesn't move, crop, or change in any way. BUT it will have a rectangular region within its boundaries (defined by me) inside which another image (IMAGE #2) must be placed. This placement needs to behave similarly to Photoshop's `Paste Into`, in that IMAGE #2 will not be distorted in any way: it will be placed inside the predefined region of IMAGE #1 and able to drag/position around (by mouse on a PC or finger on a phone). Much of IMAGE #2 will be cropped away and invisible.

Only the portion inside the defined rectangular region will be visible. Within that region, IMAGE #2 will overlay/cover/obscure the region of IMAGE #1. So a portion of IMAGE #2 will be on top of IMAGE #1, but IMAGE #2 can only live within the predefined region of IMAGE #1. IMAGE #2 needs to be *draggable* within that region. When the desired positioning is complete, I need to enable the user (via js) to capture and save the entire composite image.

Sorry to belabor the point, but in case that's not clear, let me describe it pictorially:

IMAGE #1 (fixed on the page):

[image]

Notice the blue border: that is my predefined region. Everything *outside* that region will remain the same. Everything *inside* that region will be covered by a portion of IMAGE #2.

IMAGE #2:

[image]

A cropped version of IMAGE #2 will appear inside the predefined (blue-border) region of IMAGE #1, and the user will be able to drag it around as desired until the position is satisfactory.

IMAGE #3 (the final composite):

[image]

Finally, I need the user to be able to click a button that (calling some JS) captures the composite image and enables it to be saved, or transmitted via ajax to my server. The final image needs to be high-res without any compression or degradation: just as high-res as the original images on the page.

I'm OK using a third-party library. I'm also OK doing this from scratch. But I need some guidance as to the simplest and most efficient way to do it. I'm very comfortable with HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and jQuery. Any pointers to a working example of something similar, or a library that does it, is all I'm looking for.

Comment: You'll want to use the canvas API's [`drawImage`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) function to draw the image on top of the other with the correct size, crop and position.

Comment: If it were me, I think I'd use this as an excuse to explore WebGL, which I think might be a better fit for what you are trying to do (I could be wrong though)

Comment: This is actually two things in one and it is making answering this question far more complicated than it should be. I recommend just getting the dragging working first, and possibly posting a new question for just that issue if you are having a hard time.

Comment: There are too many issues in this question. I assume the three downvotes are for it being obviously off-topic, and the three upvotes were either for sympathy or effort. Either way, the community's response to the question should be noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, you could use [draggable functionality](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) from **jQuery UI** to enable positioning for the second image. You could also use [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to capture your montage.

Since I got a cross-origin issue with the built-in snippet on Stack Overflow, please take a look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Badacadabra/m5ct0hfL/). I put the code below too:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui@1.13.2/dist/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas@1.4.1/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<p>Copy a first image and paste it here (Ctrl-V):</p>
<div id="frame"></div>
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

```css
#frame,
#container div,
#container img,
button {
  position: absolute;
}

#frame {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 5px #22bbf6;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 3;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#container div:first-child {
  z-index: 1;
}

#container div:last-child {
  width: 310px;
  height: 210px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#container img {
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

button {
  top: 270px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  let counter = 0,
      $body = $('body'),
      $p = $('p'),
      $container = $('#container'),
      frame = document.getElementById('frame');

  document.onpaste = e => {
    let fileReader = new FileReader(),
        clipItems = e.clipboardData.items;

    fileReader.onload = e => {
      counter++;

      let img = document.createElement('img');

      if (counter === 1 || counter === 2) {
        img.src = e.target.result;
        img.height = frame.offsetHeight;
      }

      if (counter === 1) {
        $p.text('Copy a second image and paste it here (Ctrl-V):');
        $container.children().first().append(img);
      } else if (counter === 2) {
        $p.text('You can adjust the position of your second image and capture your montage:');
        $container.children().last().append(img);
        $(img).draggable();
        $(img).css('cursor', 'grab');
        $body.append('<button type="button">Capture</button>');
      }
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(clipItems[clipItems.length - 1].getAsFile());
  }

  $body.on('click', 'button', () => {
    $container.css({ width: '310px', height: '210px' });

    $(frame).css('border', 'none');

    html2canvas($container[0], { scale: 2 }).then(canvas => {
      $p.text('Result:');
      $('#container, button').hide();
      $body.append(canvas);
    });
  });
  
});
```

I used a bit of **Vanilla JS** in there, especially when I found it more convenient than **jQuery**.

Notice that you can modify image quality through the `scale` option (see **html2canvas** [options](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration)).

---

**EDIT 1**

As explained in my comment, I initially put a very restrictive height to avoid large images for my demo. Your test shows that your first image has been reduced too much, so you do not see that its width can actually be larger than the frame. This is because it depends on the aspect ratio...

To give you a more insightful answer, I edited [my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Badacadabra/m5ct0hfL/). Now you can select the area (using *draggable* and *resizable* interactions from **jQuery UI**) before pasting the second image. I also defined a less restrictive height and added **html2canvas** options to make it work.

Here is the updated code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui@1.13.2/dist/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui@1.13.2/dist/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas@1.4.1/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<p>Copy a first image and paste it here (Ctrl-V):</p>
<div id="frame"></div>
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

```css
#frame,
#container,
#container div,
#container img {
  position: absolute;
}

#frame {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 5px #22bbf6;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 3;
}

#container div:first-child {
  z-index: 1;
}

#container div:last-child {
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#container img {
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

button {
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  let counter = 0,
      $body = $('body'),
      $p = $('p'),
      $container = $('#container'),
      $lastChild = $container.children().last(),
      frame = document.getElementById('frame');
      
  const verticalOffset = 3;

  function dragResizeCallback(event) {
    $lastChild.width(event.target.offsetWidth);
    $lastChild.height(event.target.clientHeight + verticalOffset);
    $lastChild.offset({
      top: event.target.offsetTop,
      left: event.target.offsetLeft
    });
  }

  document.onpaste = e => {
    let fileReader = new FileReader(),
        clipItems = e.clipboardData.items;

    fileReader.onload = e => {
      counter++;

      let img = document.createElement('img');

      if (counter === 1 || counter === 2) {
        img.src = e.target.result;
        img.height = 350;
      }

      if (counter === 1) {
        $p.text('Drag/resize the frame, then copy a second image and paste it here (Ctrl-V):');
        $container.children().first().append(img);
        $(frame).css('cursor', 'move');
        
        $(frame).draggable({
          stop: (e) => dragResizeCallback(e)
        });
        
        $(frame).resizable({
          stop: (e) => dragResizeCallback(e)
        });
      } else if (counter === 2) {
        $p.text('You can adjust the position of your second image and capture your montage:');
        $container.children().last().append(img);
        $(img).draggable();
        $(img).css('cursor', 'grab');
        $(frame).css('pointer-events', 'none');
        $p.append('<button type="button">Capture</button>');
      }
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(clipItems[clipItems.length - 1].getAsFile());
  }

  $body.on('click', 'button', () => {
    $(frame).resizable('destroy');
    $(frame).css('border', 'none');

    html2canvas($container[0], {
      width: $lastChild.width(),
      height: $lastChild.height(),
      x: $lastChild.position().left,
      y: $lastChild.position().top,
      scale: 2
    }).then(canvas => {
      $p.text('Result:');
      $('#container, button').hide();
      $body.append(canvas);
    });
  });
  
});
```

---

**EDIT 2**

If you do not want to ignore what is outside the crop area in your export, you can define a `$firstChild` variable containing `$container.children().first()` (above `$lastChild` declaration and initialization) then configure **html2canvas** like this:

```js
html2canvas($container[0], {
  width: $firstChild.find('img').width(),
  height: $firstChild.find('img').height(),
  x: $firstChild.position().left,
  y: $firstChild.position().top,
  scale: 2
})
```

Comment: Badacadabra, thank you for the detailed and thoughtful solution. I tried your jsfiddle but it seems that all it did was allow 1 image on top of another, and then draggable, and then capture the result. That's about half what I need, but the really critical piece I'm missing is to be able to paste the 2nd image into the region/crop area of the 1st image, and then be able to move around the 2nd image within the crop area, with outer portions of the inner image cropped away (hidden). That is the critical piece I need. Any ideas?

Comment: I feel that we do not see the same thing while running my JSFiddle. It is strange because I have tested it successfully on Firefox (Linux/Windows), Chrome (Windows) and Edge (Windows). What is your browser? What is your operating system? What images did you use for your test? The problem may come from `img.height = frame.offsetHeight;` that I put on purpose to avoid large images for this demo...

Comment: Badac: sorry for delay, I am using latest version of Chrome (it auto-updates about weekly). I just tried it again, and again got same thing. I will try to make a screen recording and post the link here.

Comment: Badacadabra, I made this youtube video for you, showing my experience using your JSFiddle: https://youtu.be/CBB3s0Wh1wM - looking forward to your response.

Comment: Thanks for the video! I edited my answer with some improvements. It should be OK now... ;)

Comment: Badacadabra, we are 99% of the way there. The only other thing I need is that when I click  Capture I need it to capture both images. So, the boundary of the original image #1 should be the captured image region, and it would also include the inner image #2 (which has now been moved into the correct spot).  In other words, the final capture needs to include the full region of image #1 as well as the moved/cropped image #2 within it. Here is a new youtube video I made in case that isn't clear: https://youtu.be/hAJxYYQ4BVc - THANKS!

Comment: I guess you did not see my second edit... In fact, I anticipated this request, showing you how to tweak the code. My JSFiddle demonstrates how to capture the composite image inside the crop area. But after my first edit, I read again your question and realized you would want the outer part too. ;)

Comment: I updated [my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Badacadabra/m5ct0hfL/), just in case...

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for the extensive answer. This really helps me!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small standalone example of how to do something like this with the Canvas 2D Context API.

In your example, your user would probably not choose the base image themselves but you'd get it from your server or whatnot.

```js
/**
 * Read an `Image` out of an user-selected file.
 */
function getImageFromInput(input) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = () => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = () => resolve(img);
      img.src = fr.result;
    };
    fr.onerror = reject;
    fr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  });
}

async function render() {
  let baseImg;
  let overlayImg;
  try {
    baseImg = await getImageFromInput(document.getElementById("base"));
    overlayImg = await getImageFromInput(document.getElementById("overlay"));
  } catch (e) {
    return;
  }
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = baseImg.width;
  canvas.height = baseImg.height;
  ctx.drawImage(baseImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // These would be hard-coded according to your base image.
  const x0 = canvas.width * 0.2;
  const y0 = canvas.height * 0.2;
  const x1 = canvas.width * 0.8;
  const y1 = canvas.height * 0.8;
  ctx.drawImage(overlayImg, 0, 0, overlayImg.width, overlayImg.height, x0, y0, x1 - x0, y1 - y0);
}
```

```html
Choose base image:
<input type="file" id="base" accept="image/*" onchange="render()">
<br>
Choose overlay image:
<input type="file" id="overlay" accept="image/*" onchange="render()">
<br>
<canvas width="800" height="600" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: AKX, thanks...but I need to be able to click-hold on the "inner" image (IMAGE #2) and move it around, positioning it as needed inside the bounded region. That doesn't seem to be happening for me.

Comment: Sure, but that's another concern. This just shows you how to composite two images into a single image into a given coordinate range (x0,y0,x1,y1), which is what you originally asked.

Comment: Thanks again AKX. But I did put this in my original post: "the user will be able to drag it around as desired until the position is satisfactory". Can you point me in any directions on how to achieve the drag? I'm looking at jQuery UI's draggable stuff, but I was hoping there was already a framework out there to drag, position, crop, and capture the result as a new image.

Comment: An upvote for not yielding to answer all parts of an excessively-broad, off-topic question. I have voted to close as Needs Focus.